# Вопрос про массив в классе

Tags: c++

Почему обязательно нужно писать static при объявлении длины массива в классе?
И как понять эту ошибку: нестатическая ссылка не член должна указываться относительно заданного объекта?

const int q = 10;
Myclass arr[q];

Comment: Для размера массива необходимо константное выражение, одного `const` (в данном контексте) недостаточно. Для `Myclass arr[10];` компилятор может сразу узнать размер массива, а для `const int q = read_from_user_input(); Myclass arr[q];` надо выполнить программу, чтобы узнать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const int n = 10;`

За пределами класса обозначает единственную переменную, которая инициализируется по сути во время компиляции и все время выполнения программы неизменна, так что по сути это то же, что `constexpr int n = 10;`.

Внутри класса же это не более чем переменная - поле объекта, которая инициализируется не во время компиляции, а при вызове конструктора, так что компилятор не может использовать ее как известную во время компиляции.

Но как только вы напишете ей `static`, как она "выпадает" из класса, и инициализируется во время компиляции, т.е. по сути становится как бы внешней по отношению к классу, имея с ним общее только имя.

Answer (score 0):

В С++ нельзя создать массив если его длинна зарание неизвестна.

Потому-что массив помещаеться в память, с фиксированым размером, если длинна масива не известна на этапе компиляции то линковщик не сможет правильно её распределить.

В таком случае используйте динамическую память из кучи, создайте указатель, выделите память, после использования удалите.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

int size;
std::cin >> size;
int *p = new int[size];

//используем массив как обычно, p[index] = some_value;
//ВНИМАНИЕ: в таком случае sizeof(); не вернет длинну.

delete [] p;

}
```

Comment: в случае класса можно создать пустой указатель, инициализировать с помощью new в любом удобном месте, и удалить в деструкторе, желательно проверить есть ли что удалять `if(p) delete p;`

Comment: Зачем проверять дважды? `delete` сам проверяет...

Comment: я понимаю, что можно динамически память выделять для любого размера массива. Не понятно, почему за пределами класса можно размер указать просто const int=8, а внутри уже STATIC const int=8

Comment: потому-что без модификатора статик, каждый вызов метода будет пересоздавать переменную заново, что не желательно. переменная которая инициализирует массив должна быть всегда загружена в модуль, и быть всегда статичной